# Is Async Task capable of slowing the finish() process

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I had a bunch of code that I was executing via a Handler but this changed and I ended up using an AsyncTask instead.

Now all of a sudden, when I call `finish()`, it takes an extra 10 seconds for the activity to actually finish.

Why is this happening?

My async task is only overriding `onPostExecute` and `doInBackground`.

Comment: Have you confirmed that `finish()` is actually called *while* (not after) the `AsyncTask` is running?

Comment: @AlexLockwood Its called after the async task is finished.

Comment: @AlexLockwood Also, I'm talking about the Activity.finish(), not the async task's finish

Comment: Let me see if I understand correctly. Basically what you are doing is, (1) start an async task, (2) when the async task completes you call `finish()`, (3) 10 seconds later the activity finishes? It is difficult to understand the issue without more details and/or code.

Answer (score 0):

yes for that you can do one thing :

```
1st) Make an class with context in public static variable like:

Mycommons.java

public class MyCommons
{

public static Context context;

}

2nd) Pass the context of Activity to the following public context

class MyActivity extends Activity
{
....

MyCommons.context =  MyActivity.this;
.....
}

3rd) Create one service class 

Myservice extends Asynctask
{

 ondoinbackground()
{
  // sleep for time delay 
}     

onpostexcute()
{
MyCommons.context.finish();
}
}
```

hope it will help

Comment: Why did you make the `Context` static?

Comment: @AlexLockwood becz its separate commons file and it value share with all the classes as you see in also create Myservice which also another separate class and context is also use in this class so for sharing it i make it static

Comment: its bad practice to initialize static variables inside constructors because that implies the variable is tightly coupled with an instance of a class rather than the class itself. I'm not sure I understand your argument.